# JQUERY rounding number when posting to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass $id which for exemple is 12345678909728062 (When I echo it I get this value in index.php), but when I pass it to another php-file with JQUERY it rounds it to 12345678909728060. I would like to understand why this happens? I have tested with other numbers in the id aswell with same result of rounding the last 2 digits.

```
<?php
  include 'php/header.php';
?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".r_div").load("php/items/purchase.php", {
      user_id: <?php echo $id; ?>,
      fired_button: $(this).val()
    });
  });
});


</script>

<div class="r_container">
  <div class="r_div">

<?php
  include 'php/items/store_load.php';
?>

  </div>
</div>



<?php
  include 'php/footer.php';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem being the way numbers work in programming, so passing it as a string solved the problem.

```
 user_id: "<?php echo $id; ?>",
```

Comment: This statement is not true. It's not related to the way number works. If you send numbers like `123` or `124500` it will work just fine.

Comment: In fact, i have sent the number `1234567890972806212345678909` from javascript to PHP without loosing anything.